# Facebook JS SDK - Request UI

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create a Facebook Request Dialog with JS SDK inside a Facebook page iframe tab. The dialog shows up, I can select people from my friends, I get no error not even after I click "Send Request", but my friends don`t receive the notification. This is my code:

```
FB.ui(
{
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'request'
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response); 
});
```

LATER EDIT: I uploaded a file with exactly their code from documentation on this tab: http://www.facebook.com/pages/WebTest/255282254520859?sk=app_230016043737427 , and my friends still can`t see the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run it with a Firebug / Chrome console open? Maybe an exception is being generated and dumped there.

Comment: Yes, and there is no error. Also, the response is standard request 2.0 format.